# How can I assign a local value to knockout observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am wondering is there a way to assign local variable to knockout variable?

Like example say a view model is:

```
 var index = $("#country :selected").text();
 var viewmodel = {
    CountriesList : ko.observableArray([]),
    CountryId: ko.observable(),
    Text: ko.observable(index)    

 }
```

View is :

```
<select id="country" data-bind="options: $parent.CountriesList ,optionsText: 'CountryName',optionsValue:'CountryId',value:CountryId,optionsCaption: 'Select Country..'"
            style="width: 148px">
 </select>
```

Please some one help me how could I get `optionsText` of a Drop down value? 
My `CountriesList` is an observable array which will get the values like `(CountryName:'india',CountryId:'1')` *sample.

Comment: You are looking at this backwards - you need to create a view model, with the initial values, then bind it to the UI.

Comment: please i dont have much knowledge on ko. could you please elaborate??

Comment: there are excellent tutorials on http://learn.knockoutjs.com, they will lead you from the very beginning and have a lot of code examples. Great to get some feel of the basics.

Comment: i read them so many times, examples there will not giving me any idea on how to achieve above...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Knockout Selected drop down text access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602063/knockout-selected-drop-down-text-access)

Comment: there is no answer for that question!!!

Comment: that is no reason to ask the same question again, are you going to ask the same question again if you don't get an answer for this one as well? Has it occurred to you that you might be asking your questions wrong? Maybe you should read the comment Jeroen left in your previous question again and actually do what he proposes there, which is to improve your question (that one, not this one..)

Comment: Why not drop the `optionsValue` binding and store the whole object in an observable, that way you have both the `CountryName` and `CountryId`. Just like [Example 3](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) of the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Here're two samples how you can get `optionsText`

1. Bind on `CountryId` so binding `value` contains appropriate `CountryId`
2. Bind on `CountryName` so binding `value` contains target `CountryName`

Html

```
Binding on CountryId: <select id="country" data-bind="options: CountriesList ,optionsText: 'CountryName', optionsValue:'CountryId', value: CountryId, optionsCaption: 'Select Country..'"style="width: 148px"></select>

<br/>

Binding on CountryName: <select id="country" data-bind="options: CountriesList ,optionsText: 'CountryName', optionsValue:'CountryName', value: CountryName, optionsCaption: 'Select Country..'"style="width: 148px"></select>
```

JavaScript

```
var countries = [
    { "CountryName": "India1", "CountryId": "1" },
    { "CountryName": "India2", "CountryId": "2" },
    { "CountryName": "India3", "CountryId": "3" }
]; 

var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.CountriesList = ko.observableArray(countries);
    self.CountryId = ko.observable();
    self.CountryName = ko.observable();

    self.CountryId.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        if(newValue){
            var index = newValue - 1; //because "Select Country.." is the first item
            alert(countries[index].CountryName);
        }
    }, this);

    self.CountryName.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        if(newValue){
            alert(newValue);
        }
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel);
```

You can play with code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4pG4k/3/)